# Entity framework code first convert between class boolean and column integer

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I am using `Entity Framework 5 code first`. My table has a column called `Active` and its datatype is of type `int`.  The values that are stored in Active are `0`, `1` and `null`.

I have a class that I need to map to this table.

```
public class CommandExecutionServer : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my configuration file.  I am trying to map my boolean property in my class to the integer field in the database.

```
class CommandExecutionServerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CommandExecutionServer>
{
     internal CommandExecutionServerConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("tblCommandExecutionServers");
          this.Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("Active").HasColumnType("bit");
     }
}
```

This is not working well.  The error that I am getting is:

```
The 'IsActive' property on 'CommandExecutionServer' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'
```

I tried adding `.HasColumnType("bit")` and thought that it might take of my problem.  How do I do this?  Ideally I would like 0 to be false, 1 to true, null to be null, and any other number to false.

**UPDATE**

If I change the above to:

```
this.Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("Active").HasColumnType("int");
```

...then I get the following error:

```
Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Boolean[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'IsActive' in type 'MyProject.Infrastructure.EntityFramework.CommandExecutionServer' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.int[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Active' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.CommandExecutionServer'.
```

Comment: have you tried with HasColumnType("int") ? With the same problem, I set the column type to bit in SQL server.

Comment: See my update above. Yes I would also want to set it to bit but it's not my server so I can't go change table structures :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework C# convert int to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577711/entity-framework-c-sharp-convert-int-to-bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following because I do not know if Entity Framework can handle the conversion for me.

I removed this line:

```
this.Property(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnName("Active").HasColumnType("int");
```

I then added a property to my `CommandExecutionServer class`:

```
public class CommandExecutionServer : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int? Active { get; set; }

     public bool IsActive
     {
          get
          {
               return (Active == 1) ? true : false;
          }
     }
}
```

There might be a better way but this works for me for now. If any one can better this then please go ahead :)

Comment: the point here is: IsActive is unknown from the sql server, so if you query using this field in a where, you'll have to get all the table lines client side. BTW, have you an Ignore(x => x.IsActive) in your context ? And if not, Does the mapping run UnExceptionnaly ?

Comment: No I don't have it as Ignore.  No exception this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT   CONVERT(A.bitcolumn as bit) as bitout
```

ado.net will convert bits to bools. So, just convert your integer to a bit in your select statement in t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework Core you can use `Value Conversions` like this:

```
class CommandExecutionServerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CommandExecutionServer>
{
     internal CommandExecutionServerConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("tblCommandExecutionServers");
          this.Property(x => x.IsActive)
          .HasColumnName("Active")
          .HasConversion<int>();
     }
}
```

Similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577711/entity-framework-c-sharp-convert-int-to-bool/77928807#77928807)

You can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#built-in-converters)