# Column type is lost only when using one-to-one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

My legacy SQL Server database stores bool values as integers.

I know how to setup this conversion. And it works in simple queries like:

```cs
var query = db.TableChild.Select(a => new { a.BoolField }).ToList();
```

But when doing query with one-to-one relation the exception has occurred:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 'System.Boolean' but the actual value was of type 'System.Int32'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'.

If I change the relation to table join or use an Include, everything works fine, types are converted.

Bad query with exception:

```cs
var query = db.TableParent
    .Where(a => a.Child != null)
    .Select(a => new { a.Child.BoolField })
    .ToList();
```

Relation is created as:

```cs
entityTypeChild
    .HasOne(b => b.Parent)
    .WithOne(a => a.Child)
    .HasForeignKey<TableChild>(b => b.ParentRefId)
    .HasPrincipalKey<TableParent>(a => a.RefId);
```

Tables are mapped as:

```cs
class TableParent
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RefId { get; set; }

    public TableChild Child { get; set; }
}

class TableChild
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ParentRefId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public bool BoolField { get; set; }

    public TableParent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Produced SQL is normal:

```sql
SELECT [a.Child].[BoolField]
FROM [TableParent] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [TableChild] AS [a.Child] ON [a].[RefId] = [a.Child].[ParentRefId]
WHERE [a.Child].[Id] IS NOT NULL
```

I expect this linq query to work without exceptions and not ignore `Column(TypeName = "int")` attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework C# convert int to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577711/entity-framework-c-sharp-convert-int-to-bool)

Comment: I've submitted an issue to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15200